# how to get rid of shadow/dark artifacts on object?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shadows, artifacts

I am trying to render a very high resolution mesh with an image texture applied.

I don't know why, but I end up with all these black faces or shadow artifacts (not sure what they are).

Using cycles, it produces the below image. Eevee seems to render fine?

[image]

I've tried:

```
-smooth modifier
-smooth shading, flat shading
-recalculating normals, flipping normals, etc.
-edge split modifier
-shadow terminator offset
-path / branched path cycles rendering
-denoising of render
-messing with camera clipping
```

At first I thought it was just a normal issue, but I can't seem to fix them. Still think it might be a normal issuee..

Any help is appreciated, FYI it seems to work fine on a lower resolution mesh, but this super high resolution results in the weird artifacts.

There are also some blue and some black edges in edit mode (not sure what colors mean, but assuming it's not right)

[image]

Comment: The blue edges look like they are marked sharp - select the whole mesh in edit mode, right click and select "clear sharp". Also, that is some pretty complex topology for what looks like little more than 2 planes connected by a "ramp". Try adding a Decimate Modifier set to "Planar" to simplify it substantially. If you view your mesh in Object Mode - Wireframe Preview, you can see what the modifier is doing before you apply it. See if that helps. Lastly, because it happens in Cycles and not eevee, it makes me think you might be using a displacement shader - is this the case?

Comment: thanks ill try this.. and it's actually high res lidar with a aerial image texture, I used the full data to see how good I could get it XD..and no I was not using a displacement shader..